# Download multiple files through FireFox

Tags: http, firefox

Is there any possible way using FireFox to download multiple files from a server? So far I have explored

- zipping files (using embedded device, may not be enough space)
- flash downloaders (doesn't seem possible)
- for loop (spams FireFox save dialog, not practical for 100s of files)
- FTP client (defeats the purpose obviously)

Ideally I would like my users to select a bunch of files from the server and have it download to their HD by clicking one button. FireFox must be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can access ftp sites via your browser and it use it like a file explorer, downloading multiple files at once.  There are two methods I know of:  a. http://{url} (pointing at an ftp site that allows http access) and it should prompts for user name and password   b. ftp://{username}:{password}@{url}.   e.g. ftp://myusername:mypass@mysite.com

here is an article on the [ftp method](https://www.siteground.com/kb/ftp_browser/)